# Most efficient way to store 'access codes' for users in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Suppose my web service costed $5 per month and the user is given an access code inorder to log in to other devises (tablet/phone) after he registered on his computer.

It wouldn't be safe to store his/her code adjacent to the user id in the table on my database. Im not asking anyone to help decide my architecture but how do companies usually store special information like this?

I was thinking in the users local cache (sqlLite) to store a key and the database (mysql) to store another private key like a hash but what is the **standard**?

Comment: The "standard" is to store access codes, like all other account information, in a secure location.  How you structure it beyond that is really up to you...

Answer (score 0):

What's not "safe" about it? Create a table for access tokens that's related to your users. This is typically what's done for systems that allow multiple devices to connect to a single account.

For example, if you have a GitHub account, have a look at your [GitHub Security Settings](https://github.com/settings/security) to see how the've done it. They have an option to "revoke" access to the various sessions that are described by a token.

Comment: It just sounds 'too easy' to have name1 and name1accesscode adjacent to eachother, with the login system (that doesnt need codes after first time) authenticating from that same table. SQLInjection could really take advantage of that

Comment: Then have two different tables?  What's "too easy" about it?  Too easy for a hacker to get in and muck with?  If there's someone malicious *in* your database, you already have bigger problems than adjacent data.

Comment: I just imagined something much more complex. No issue

Comment: @BDillan If you've got SQL injection bugs, it's game over anyway, doesn't matter how you've stored your data. Thats' why using data placeholders like `?` and code auditing is **exceptionally** important. You don't engineer for disasters by scrambling your data, as anyone who snapshots your database through a hole will figure it out in a few seconds, while you'll spend hundreds of hours dealing with your oddball schema. Just use the simplest thing that works.

Comment: If you're worried about potential abuse, you can always set up an alarm to trigger if an unusual number of tokens is used by a single IP address. That's a lot better than trying to hide things, which is basically impossible.